# Custom WordPress Theme add in WordPress theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

How to add custom WordPress theme in WordPress theme using PHP, CSS, HTML...I tried
C:\Users\megha\Downloads\wordpress-5.8.zip\wordpress\wp-content\themes in this way to show theme but nothing happen ..then how to insert theme in wordpress

Comment: You install the theme after installing wordpress. I sugest having a look at [How to install WordPress](https://wordpress.org/support/article/how-to-install-wordpress/) and [Using Themes](https://wordpress.org/support/article/using-themes/).

Answer (score 0):

- [Installing WordPress themes and plugins][1] is very simple. All you have to do is go to the `WordPress dashboard`, there you will have the menu on the left. Select plugins/themes.
- You can also search the `directory`, and apply filters to find a theme or plugin that best suits your needs. Click on install, then click activate, and voila! It’s done, my friend. You have successfully manually installed a theme/plugin on your website!
- To use full-site editing, hover your cursor on Appearance, and in the menu select Editor. Voila! You can now edit your homepage, and create a design you want. For those looking forward to design ideas or ready-made blocks, check out WordPress Patterns.
- Most importantly, there is no restriction on the number of plugins you can use (unless you have managed hosting, as most do not allow some plugins, especially those that clash with their platform’s codes. Read more here: managed vs self-hosting).
- So, you can pick any number of plugins you want, and don’t worry about how to customize WordPress plugins or how to update WordPress plugins. It’s very simple and happens at the click of a button. We’ll be coming up with more guides, clearing any remaining whiff of doubt you might have.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).